# Restrict a user to input data in a particular pattern in a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<TextBox Name="Cnic" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

I want to restrict the user to enter the data in the text box in the following pattern for example 34101-1234567-8.

I want to restrict the user to put only numbers in this format with two dashes included in the given place.

Comment: Please suggest me the code for the above problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are no free coding service. Please show some research effort, what you have tried and where you got stuck.